# Get all elements after a certain index in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to retrieve all elements after a starting index from a list
and **return an empty list if out of range**.

```
List myList = [1,2,3,4,5];
print([2:]) // returns [3,4,5]
print([6:]) // returns []
```

How do I do that in dart?

Comment: @julemand101 Many developers are not looking at the documentation in the first place, but they do search in Google, even for simple solutions. Since It was difficult for me to find such an answer, I decided to post this question, so others won't struggle to find it. That's the idea behind StackOverflow, making searching for a solution - easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [`skip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/skip.html) method is for. If you look at the documentation for it, it has the behavior you desire.

```dart
List<int> myList = [1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> newList = myList.skip(2).toList();
print(newList); //[3, 4, 5]
```

```dart
List<int> myList = [1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> newList = myList.skip(5).toList();
print(newList); //[]
```

Comment: What is wrong with `sublist` on `List`? :)

Comment: @julemand101 OP said they want "If It's out of range I want to return an empty list." `subList` won't allow that.

Comment: Ahh did not see that detail. Thanks :)